# Construir json con varios arrays

Tags: angularjs, json, http, post

Tengo un api que recibe este json:

```
{
    "instructions":[
        {
            "A":9,
            "B":1,
            "move":"moveover"
        },
        {
            "A":8,
            "B":1,
            "move":"moveover"
        }
        ],
        "length":10,
        "res":""
}
```

Y me regresa el siguiente:

```
{
  "instructions": [
    {
      "A": 9,
      "B": 1,
      "move": "moveover"
    },
    {
      "A": 8,
      "B": 1,
      "move": "moveover"
    }
  ],
  "length": 10,
  "res": "Position [0] :  0Position [1] :  1 9 8Position [2] :  2Position [3] :  3Position [4] :  4Position [5] :  5Position [6] :  6Position [7] :  7Position [8] : Position [9] : "
}
```

los datos los tomo de la siguiente página web/formulario: 
[image: Formulario]
Lo que hago es guardar en un array los valores de A,B y los movimientos, por ejemplo:

```
//lo que tendria en memoria 
var A=[1,3,5,8];
var B=[5,6,7,10];
var moves=[moveinto,moveover,pileover,pileinto];
//añadiendo los valores al array 
$scope.addMove = function () {
     A.push($scope.addA);
     B.push($scope.addB);
     moves.push($scope.addMov);
}
```

mi duda es ¿cómo armar el json para poder mandarlo por post?

una idea que tuve fue:

```
for (var i = 0; i < serverA.length; i++) {
      objetoJson[i] = {
        "instructions": [{
          "A": serverA[i],
          "B": serverB[i],
          "move": serverMove[i]
        }],
        "length": $scope.blockLength,
        "res": null
      };
```

pero no me funcionó, ahora lo que hice fue mandarlo manual y si me funciona:

```
json = {
      "instructions": [{
          "A": 9,
          "B": 1,
          "move": "moveover"
        },
        {
          "A": 8,
          "B": 1,
          "move": "moveover"
        }
      ],
      "length": 10,
      "res": ""
    }
    $http.post("http://localhost:56493/api/BlocksProblem", json)
      .then(function (data) {
        $scope.result = data;
      }, function (response) {
        $scope.result = response;
      });
```

¿me podrían decir como armar mi json?

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que estás generando un arreglo de objetos cuando lo que tienes que generar es un objeto con una llave instructions que tiene como valor un arreglo, esto se arregla generando el arreglo de instructions y después generando el objeto con las llaves que necesitas:

Primero, desde tu controlador ya genera la estructura de las instrucciones de la siguiente forma:

```
var instructions = [];

$scope.addMove = function () {

    instructions.push({
        A: $scope.addA,
        B: $scope.addB,
        move: $scope.addMov
    });
}
```

posteriormente crea tu json de la siguiente manera:

```
json = {
    instructions: instructions,
    length: $scope.blockLength,
    res: ""
}
```

Y ya está listo para que lo mandes a tu API.

Saludos!

Comment: ya lo pude arreglar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

YA LO SOLUCIONE, MUCHAS GRACIAS A TODOS , ESTA FUE MI SOLUCION:

leyendo es stackoverflow en ingles me encontre con esto:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250953/how-do-i-create-javascript-array-json-format-dynamically

Asi que procedi a crear la mia:

```
    //Guardo los valores que obtengo del form en arrays 
    var serverMove = [];
    var serverA = [];
    var serverB = [];
    //create the json 
    var jsonS = {
          instructions: [],
          "length": $scope.blockLength,
          "res": ""
    };
       //lleno dinamicamente unicamente la parte de instrucciones
        for (var i = 0; i < serverA.length; i++) {
          jsonS.instructions.push({
            "A": serverA[i],
            "B": serverB[i],
            "move": serverMove[i]
          })
        }
```

el json resultante queda algo asi :

```
{ 
    "instructions": [
        { 
            "A": 1
            , "B": 3,
            "move": 
            "moveonto" 
        },
        { 
            "A": 5,
            "B": 9, 
            "move": "pileover" 
        } 
        ], 
        "length": 22, 
        "res": "" 
}
```

espero que le resulte de utilidad a alguien

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo manejar todo como un array y luego al momento de necesitar el Json lo parseas de esta forma:

```
var json = [1,2,3,4];
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: En el caso de la pregunta, está manejando objetos. ¿Podrías detallar cómo sería en ese caso?